# What does the word "please" do?

Tags: word-usage, ambiguity, dialects

Does *please* make any statement a question? Is it polite?

"TAKE OUT THE TRASH" vs. "Take out the trash, *please*" is one an option?

My son says when I say *please* it makes it a question, so he never does any chores! Also, some of Midwesterner folks use it in place of "what?" or "come again?"

Comment: _Please_ is an interjection that may also be used as an adverb. It's related to the verb _to please_, as in _That does not please me_. It got the way it is because it used to be short for _if it please you_ (we'd say _if it pleases you_ in Modern English), and the little words got rubbed off, as they always do. What it does is mark the sentence as an officially polite request -- mothers are always telling children to "say _please_". It matches _thank you_ (short for _I thank you_), which you say after your request is granted (or, even better, as soon as it's heard).

Comment: so, wouldnt "if it pleases you" mean it is a question?

Comment: No, it would mean that it's a choice. What your son is telling you is that it doesn't please him. But he's wrong; you're not giving him a choice if you don't use the full formula; once it gets the little words rubbed off it's not magic any more. Otherwise, it's just evidence that you're trying to be polite, the way grownups try to talk.

Comment: That depends on if you put a question mark after it, or instead put a period or exclamation point.  When spoken (or yelled) it depends on if you raise or lower the inflection at the end.  It can be either.

Comment: Oh, intonation can get in the way of politeness in a million ways. Everybody knows that.

Comment: I'm sorry this question was closed.  "Please" makes an order or request more polite by qualifying a "felicity condition" on the performance of the order or making of the request.  Although it has become conventional, it goes back to "if it pleases you to comply",  The matter is explained very well in a dissertation by my friend Jim Heringer: http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED062850.pdf .

Comment: This podcast - http://www.theallusionist.org/allusionist/please - discusses some of the differences between the use of please in the UK and US - in the UK it is very much used for a polite request however in some parts of the US it can be seen as talking down to someone - like when giving a servant an instruction.

Comment: You may also be interested in the notion of "Requests as questions," as explained in the _Chicago Manual of Style_ (16th edition): "A request disguised as a question does not require a question mark. Such formulations can usually be reduced to the imperative. [Examples:] Would you kindly respond by March 1. _or_ Please respond by March 1." So when you instruct someone (in writing) to do something but frame the request/order in the form of a question, you need not punctuate it with a question mark, according to _Chicago_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your question, Darlene.

Let's break your question into smaller chunks here:

**1. Does using "please" change a statement into a question?**

Yes it could.

It depends on how your voice is inflected. As when the speaker makes a question, his/her voice reflects the question, at the end of the sentence statement.

[image]

You can see the rising and falling of voice inflection in two sentences here:

1. It looks quite different. [Statement, falling intonation at the end]
2. Do you like oysters? [Question, rising intonation at the end]

Thus, if we turn the statement {Take out the trash.] into a question, using "please" {Take out the trash, please?}; it is entirely possible- by the rising intonation at the end of the sentence.

**2. Does using "please" mean you are being polite?**

**3. Does using "please" means you are giving the other person an option of "YES or NO" and not a "MUST".**

Questions 2 and 3 both refer to the speaker's purpose or intent.

If the speaker intended to be polite: "Take out the trash, please." Using please helps to soften the command commonly associated with the action verb: "Take..".

If the speaker intended to give the receiver/the other person a choice, to agree or to reject: "Do your chores, please [YES .... NO]".

This is different from: "Do your chores [MUST]."

**4. Does using "please" equal to "What?" or "Come Again?"**

This is also a possible function of using "please", at the end of a statement-turned-question.

Where, depending on local usage of that particular area, people can use "what" and "come again" as fillers/substitutes of "please" for the function of requesting clarification.

Say it, [please?]. [Please= clarification]

Say it, [what?]. [What= clarification]

Say it, [come again?]. [Come again= clarification]

Comment: Surely the 4th query is about the stand-alone usage of 'Please?' mirroring 'Plaît-il?'.

Comment: Thank you for your question.

If it is standalone, from the English usage standpoint, it will still be about the function of requesting clarification.

Is the French "plait-il" for the same function?

Comment: But you address 'using "please" ... **at the end of** a statement-turned-question'. As OP shows, it can be stand-alone. I'd write 'This is another possible function of  "please", at the end of a spelled-out request (see below) or as deleted to the single word request.'

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely correct about "please" being a strange word. In fact, both "please" and "thank you" were constructions that were a demarcation of an older English class structure having to do with lords, ladies, and peasants (or anyone in a lower class). The origins have long been forgotten and it's taken as politeness.

Since you are "in charge" of your son, saying "please" could be perceived by him as you putting him either equal to, or above you. Hah! Just tell him, "Take out the trash."